# If Index And Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I've got a function that uses If, Index, And, and Match. It is supposed to change the desired value when I toggle a built-in drop-down table that has 2 options ("good" and "bad"). If "good" is selected, the desired cell gives a result of "3". If "bad" is selected, I erroneously get an "N/A" error. I've racked my brain and all I can think of is there is some text/number issues with the match.. any suggestions? Here is the formula:

`=IF(AND(MATCH(B2,$AO$2:$AO$31,0),MATCH("Good",$AU$2:$AU$31,0),C2="SG"),3,IF(AND(MATCH(B2,$AO$2:$AO$31,0),MATCH("Bad",$AU$2:$AU$31,0),C2="SG"),-5))`

Comment: care to expound on the down vote? that would help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `MATCH` as a test on it's own because it doesn't return `TRUE/FALSE`, it returns either a number or `#N/A` error, so if there is no match the formula errors out, use `ISNUMBER` function wrapped around `MATCH` to return `TRUE/FALSE` as required in this situation, e.g. in place of your first `MATCH` use

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$AO$2:$AO$31,0))`

...and the same for the other MATCH functions

...or you can use `COUNTIF` which will return a positive number (a match) or a zero (no match) e.g.

`=COUNTIF($AO$2:$AO$31,B2)`

In an IF function any non-zero number will equate to TRUE and zero to FALSE

Comment: The 1st option using ISNUMBER worked to perfection!! Absolutely fantastic explanation of Why it works as well.. I have a better understanding, and renewed vigor to finish this monster. Thanks so much Houdini!